# How to send an email from a Webix application using sendmail of node JS server at the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendmail, webix

I want to send an email from a webix application by clicking a button in the UI, which will send a post request through an ajax call to the node JS server at the backend. 
The webix part looks like below:

```
{   id:'tb',
    view: 'toolbar',
    cols: [

    {view:"button", id:"mail_btn", type:"icon", label:"SendEmail", tooltip:"Send an email",  width:100, on: {onItemClick:function(){sendEmail()}} },     
       ]
}
```

The callback function:

```
function sendEmail() {        
    var bodypart = {"message" : "This is a test mail"};        
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/appl/email',
          data: bodypart,
          success: function (data) {
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                error: function(err){
                   console.log(err);
                    }
                });
  }
}
```

The above ajax call sends a request to the node JS where I am using sendmail npm package to achieve this. The code looks like below :

```
var sendmail = require('sendmail')();

app.post('/appl/email', sendmail());

    function sendEmail() {
      sendmail({
        from: 'xyz@support.com',
        to: 'abc@support.com',
        subject: 'test sendmail',
        html: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
      }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
        console.dir(reply);
    });

    }
```

However, I am getting below error :

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

Is there a way to send email from webix itself without sending the request to node JS server ?
Or else how to use the sendmail npm package to achieve this the way I am trying  ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not in the way you are using sendmail, but rather in the way you are using express routes.

Here is a sample code I just whipped up that gave me the same error you got in your code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app =  express();

app.get('/', doSomething());

function doSomething() {
    console.log('this is a sample test');
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is running'));
```

The issue is that `app.get`, and the same would be true for `app.post`, has a certain signature it requires. The function that gets passed in is supposed to have the `req` and `res` arguments. You can also optionally add the `next` argument last.

This is how my above code would fixed.

```
const express = require('express');
const app =  express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    doSomething();
    res.json('success');
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log('this is a sample test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I corrected it and it is working now.